# divergence problem with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

How can I show that $\nabla \cdot (\phi \nabla )=0$. when $\phi (r, \theta)=(r+\frac{R^2}{r})\cos\theta, r> R $?

Comment: do you mean $\nabla \cdot \phi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by $\nabla \cdot (\phi \nabla)$. You probably mean $\nabla \cdot (\nabla\phi )=\nabla ^2\phi$ which is indeed zero. You can show it by using the following expression for the Laplacian in polar coordinates:
\begin{equation}
\nabla ^2 \phi(r,\theta)=
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}  \right)+
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \theta^2}  .
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't get zero tho ... And i'm pretty sure I did the partial derivates correctly.

Comment: check again, I have checked and I get zero!